# Nginx SSL Redirect - from http://exaple.com to https://%2A.exaple.com/

Tags: http, ssl, redirect, nginx, https

I'm having problems getting my nginx server to work.

My default site config looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

When i type example.com or http://example.com into my adress bar nginx redirects to https://... but it always attaches %2A. infront of the domain so the result looks like https://%2A.example.com.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: it is working for me

Comment: Do you have any thing related to *.example.com in server_name or somewhere in block looks like nginx is pretending $host to *.example.com.

Comment: In my other default server  block which handles SSL the servername is server_name _.